# Формы частиц б vs бы

Tags: наклонение, частицы

Анализируя частотность использования полной и сокращенной частицы *бы*, Comtet пишет:

> Если верить достоверности записей этого сборника ("*Русская разговорная
>   речь*"), оказывается, усеченная форма "б" довольно редка в разговорной
>   речи, то есть именно там, где можно было бы ее прежде всего ожидать.
>   Это тем более неожиданно, что разговорную речь обычно связывают с
>   быстрым темпом, при котором слова выступают в редуцированных формах.

Проанализировала огромное количество примеров (также много диалогов). Oказалось автор статьи прав.

Ушла **бы** я от тебя, но не могу.

Ушла **б** я от тебя, но не могу.

Формы с *б* встречаются намного реже. Мне стало интересно, почему так. Использовать сокращенную форму считается "необразованным"?

Спасибо!

PD: у меня есть чувство, что плохо сформулировала вопрос. надеюсь вы меня понимаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На выбор частиц БЫ/Б влияют разные факторы, нельзя говорить только о темпе разговорной речи.

1) **Первый фактор –  фонетический.**

Частицы б, ж, ль употребляются только после слов, **оканчивающихся на гласные буквы.**
[https://orfogrammka.ru/орфография/раздельное_написание_сочетаний_с_частицами/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/)

**После согласных** частица Б точно не пишется, например: ***как бы мне.***.. (только частица БЫ), да и в других случаях фонетика тоже важна.

Надо учитывать стечение **согласных, расположенных вблизи частицы.**  Например, чаще употребляется выражение ***если б мне***..., чем ***когда б мне*** (и в первую очередь это касается **смычных** согласных Г, Д и др.)

**Перед согласными Б/П** частица Б реже используется (произносить неудобно): ***если б было***...

***Ушла б я от тебя***. Частица Б оглушается (произносится как П), смысл фразы становится менее ясным. В некоторых случаях это приходится  учитывать.

Таким образом, **выигрывая в краткости, мы можем проиграть в удобстве произношения и понимания.**

2) **Второй фактор – это стиль.**

Если же фонетика конкретной фразы позволяет использовать частицу Б, то становится важным стиль: частица Б действительно характерна **для разговорной и художественной речи,** а в официальной книжной ее не стоит применять.

3) **В стихах** важна ритмика, то есть количество гласных, от этого зависит выбор частицы.

Поэтому чтобы сделать вывод о частотности, нужно **сравнивать употребление частиц в сходных фонетических вариантах.**

Answer (score 1):

Анонимушка, здравствуй, давно не виделись! )))

Никакое "б" не "необразованное", а вполне литературное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И просто-таки рекомендумое в предложениях, где необходимо обозначить два условия. Одно из них изображаем с помощью "б", другое - "бы" (просто чтоб не повторяться!).

*Если бы ты понимала **мой** язык, я б научила тебя русскому разговорному, которым дышат...*